# I know what I want, but I don't know how to do it! (chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I've got something I want to make - it's a little script/code/app/extension or something similar which will perform a very specific task for me. I have no coding experience whatsoever and I've been going through the chrome basic developing guide for a week and don't feel I'm getting anywhere. I've got a very specific thing I want to do, and I don't want to waste time learning things that aren't necessary to achieving it. I'm not asking anyone here to do the work for me, I just need some pointers in the right direction as to what to learn. Without further ado! Here is what I want my program to do! (ta da!):

The primary function of the product is to refresh the booking page for a specific website, and when the date that I want to book becomes available, to select it in order to reserve it, and then notify me that the date has appeared. So! :

1. Refresh booking page periodically.
2. When a range of dates becomes available (e.g. any date between March 15th and April 15th), to select the earliest one (by highlighting it and then clicking on it, as you would with a mouse). Ideally I could select this range of dates from the icon next to the OmniBox.
3. A box will then appear asking if I'd like to 'continue' or 'cancel'. I want the script to hit continue for me, so my date is reserved.
4. I want to be notified when this happens, as the date is only reserved for 15 minutes and the page will time out if I don't proceed with the booking in that time. Receiving a text would be great, but this I imagine is too ambitious. So a notification (which I've sort of learnt how to do) would work.

What do you guys think? As I said I have no experience whatsoever with coding. Do you think it would be easier to do what I want to do some other way? i.e. not with a chrome extension but with an independent script or an app or something. I have no idea what I'm doing. As I said, I just would like some pointers in the right direction, not for anyone to do the dirty work for me.

Thanks for taking the time to read.

Best,
Andrew

Comment: There are no shortcuts.  You should learn some programming basics in Javascript, HTML and CSS first.  Otherwise, you're going to spin your wheels for weeks, and wind up in the same place: at the starting line.  You should then be able to follow [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted).

Answer (score 1):

There is already an extension that does something similiar.

Try out [iMacros from Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imacros-for-chrome/cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp?hl=en)

This extension will allow you to build a list of repeating tasks and rules.  You should be able to come close to what you're wanting using this extension.